Why does `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/ --recursive | wc -l` list fewer files than the number of objects mentioned in the AWS web UI in my S3 bucket?
I have an AWS S3 bucket s3://mybucket/. Running the following command to count all files:
aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/ --recursive | wc -l

outputs: 279847
Meanwhile, the AWS console web UI clearly indicates 355,524 objects:

Why does aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/ --recursive | wc -l list fewer files than the number of objects mentioned in the AWS web UI in my S3 bucket?

Replying to comments:
Bucket versioning is enabled:


Do you have versioning enabled?

@AlexD thanks, bucket versioning is enabled:
https://i.sstatic.net/4k5qw.png

Follow-up question: How can I use the AWS CLI to match the number of objects mentioned in the AWS web UI in my S3 bucket?

When you have versioning enabled, each file version counts as a separate object in the bucket. You can list all versions of objects with the aws s3api CLI command:
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket mybucket

